# Javascript regular expression for vehicle number

Tags: javascript, regex

Would someone write a regular expression to validate a vehicle number in text box with the below format:

> MH-01-XX-0001

i.e. Alphabets in 1st 2 characters, special character '-', then two numbers, special character '-', then two alphabets, special character '-' and then 4 digit number.

Comment: Have you tried anything (e.g. reading a regex tutorial)?

Comment: are only uppercase alphabets required?

Comment: The first two characters aren't "alphabets", they're *letters*. Or "alphabetic" characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a very simple tasks. Try this:

```
^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}$
```

- The `[A-Z]` means the capital alphabet characters.
- The `\d` means digits.
- The numbers between curved brackets `{..}` means how many times the preceding should be repeated.
- The `^` means the beginning of the string and the `$` means the end of it.

Comment: Thank you that works like charm :)